# Windows Batch File Nested For Loops

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Having a midlife crisis with this one. I have a txt file with a list of files and filesize that I am looping through and comparing to what is actually found on disk. The list of files is a remote file on another server.

Data:

```
\videos\20201103-0_FastestLap2017WorldTimeAttackMCAS13Silvia1.20.9.mp4|72184632
\videos\20201103-0_WTAC2015SteveKasWTACR34GTRSkylinePreWTACTestingatSydneyMotorsportPark.mp4|402572676
\videos\20201103-0_WTAC2016MCASuspensionHammerheadS13TimSlade1.22.19.mp4|353526548
\images\20201103-0_FeatDOP_4283.jpg|421791
\images\20201103-0_battles4.jpg|835931
\images\20201103-0_3N8A3099copy.jpg|1696647
\videos\20201103-0_ATTACKbestonboardlapsofWTAC2018RP968HammerheadXtremeGTR.TRB03andmore.mp4|406519905
```

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET TestDir=S:\Documents\testplatform\data\
@ECHO Checking %TestDir%    
    
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET ActualSize=0

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%i in (%TestDir%\files.txt) do (

    for %%A in (%TestDir%%%i) do (
        set ActualSize=%%~zA
    )

    @ECHO File: %%i, Server Size: %%j, ActualSize: !ActualSize!
)

PAUSE
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
```

The issue is, no matter how I try and use %% or !!, I cant get ActualSize to display the Actual Size. I know its something to do with set ActualSize=%%~zA not having the correct scoping within the batch file.

```
Checking S:\Documents\testplatform\data\
File: \videos\20201103-0_FastestLap2017WorldTimeAttackMCAS13Silvia1.20.9.mp4, Server Size: 72184632, ActualSize:
File: \videos\20201103-0_WTAC2015SteveKasWTACR34GTRSkylinePreWTACTestingatSydneyMotorsportPark.mp4, Server Size: 402572676, ActualSize:
File: \videos\20201103-0_WTAC2016MCASuspensionHammerheadS13TimSlade1.22.19.mp4, Server Size: 353526548, ActualSize:
File: \images\20201103-0_FeatDOP_4283.jpg, Server Size: 421791, ActualSize:
File: \images\20201103-0_battles4.jpg, Server Size: 835931, ActualSize:
File: \images\20201103-0_3N8A3099copy.jpg, Server Size: 1696647, ActualSize:
File: \videos\20201103-0_ATTACKbestonboardlapsofWTAC2018RP968HammerheadXtremeGTR.TRB03andmore.mp4, Server Size: 406519905, ActualSize:
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you really expect windows to locate a filepath that contains `\\/` after the root folderpath? ie: `rootfolder\\/subfolder/filenamene.ext` - because that's what you've scripted

Comment: This is an issue. I’ll resolve this issue and update.

Comment: this has fixed the problem. LEGEND!

Comment: @T3RR0R will not see your comment, if you do not address him with an `@` I have done that for you now.

Comment: there is one other benefit/drawback to using broken labels  `::` as a comment in scripts, so long as used outside of parenthetical blocks. _The broken label does not output any information even when you have `ECHO ON` while `REM` comments DO output information, including contents of variables when you have `ECHO ON`  using `::` at the top of a script is most common usage because it can occur truely before any code even `ECHO OFF` and not spit out long header comments to screen, making that portion truely sperable from the rest of the code.  Use them tactically along with `REM`.

Answer (score 1):

`:: get the filesize of each file and save it in ActualSize` is an illegal statement. Remove it or convert it to a **Remark** (aka comment) - `REM get the filesize of each file and save it in ActualSize`.

You are posting illegal code that you found and asking why illegal code doesn't work. **Because it is illegal**.

`:` is a `Goto` destination known as a `label` in Windows command line interface.

Type `rem /?` and `goto /?`.

Comment: @DanielBartley : No. `::` is a broken label - a label that can't be reached. Consequently, it can, and often is, used as a comment as it's shorter, visually less intrusive and easier to type than `rem`. But label it is, and therefore it cannot be used within a `block statement` (parenthesised series of statements). OK- there are some esoteric exceptions, but the easiest way is to simply replace the `::` with `rem ` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: @DanielBartley There are thousands of questions here where this is the problem - and each poster argues about it. Because they **found it on the internet**.

Comment: The more you know. No more comments in batch files

Comment: @DanielBartley - wrong takeaway - `rem` is the comment character string. It was introduced in 1981.

Comment: @Daniel Bartley there is one other benefit/drawback to using broken labels  `::` as a comment in scripts, so long as used outside of parenthetical blocks. _The broken label does not output any information even when you have `ECHO ON` while `REM` comments DO output information, including contents of variables when you have `ECHO ON`  using `::` at the top of a script is most common usage because it can occur truely before any code even `ECHO OFF` and not spit out long header comments to screen, making that portion truely sperable from the rest of the code.  Use them tactically along with `REM`.

Comment: Also `illegal` is the wrong term, and will be interpreted very aggressively as it implies a transgression against the law.  There is no `law`, there is a `best practice`, and even that is a guideline that is malleable.

Comment: Illegal is the correct term. Legal code is written to spec.

Answer (score 0):

working code:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET TestDir=S:\Documents\testplatform\data\
SET MaxDifference=256
@ECHO Checking %TestDir%

    
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET ActualSize=0

:: loop over the test data file
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%i in (%TestDir%\files.txt) do (

    :: get the filesize of each file and save it in ActualSize
    for %%A in (%TestDir%%%i) do (
        SET /A ActualSize=0
    SET /A ActualSize=%%~zA
    )

    
    SET /A Difference=!ActualSize!-%%j
    IF !Difference! LSS 0 SET /A Difference=!Difference!*-1
    IF !Difference! GTR !MaxDifference! (
        @ECHO File: %%i, Server Size: %%j, ActualSize: !ActualSize!, Difference: !Difference!
    )
)
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

PAUSE
```

Outputs:

```
Checking S:\Documents\testplatform\data\
File: /playlist-1.html, Server Size: 6360, ActualSize: 6581, Difference: 221
File: /playlist-2.html, Server Size: 6340, ActualSize: 6561, Difference: 221
File: /playlist-3.html, Server Size: 6396, ActualSize: 6617, Difference: 221
File: /playlist-6.html, Server Size: 6385, ActualSize: 6606, Difference: 221
Press any key to continue . . .
```